# Windows 8.1 app asset name qualifier warning, randomly disappearing images

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

This is a warning which I get while Building a Windows 8.1 App project in Visual Studio 2013 For Windows:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1706,9): warning APPX1621: A mixture of images matching logical name 'Assets\SquareLogo30\SquareLogo30.png' exists in this project with and without the "scale" or "targetsize" qualifier specified. For predictable runtime behavior, explicitly specify the scale or target size in each image asset's file name.
```

Yes, I "explicitly specified the scale or target size in each image asset's file name" - [this is how my assets are named.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXlVY.png)

[In the manifest, images are displayed correctly and without any errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVZMt.png) (visuals removed due to copyright)

But I still get that warning.

Also, sometimes during usage of the app, some images randomly disappear from tiles / taskbar shortcut / taskbar preview corner (*i.stack.imgur.com/nyCTb.png* - SO does not let me to post more than 2 links, need at least 10 reputation...).

So yes, this warning is causing me that "unpredictable behavior".

My question: how should I name the assets, so that I could **use the unplated** versions of the Icons and **resolve** the unpredictable behavior (the warning itself)?

Write a comment, if you need some more specific info! :)

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2015 and also experiencing this behavior